# JSTL - Decimal format of input type="number"

Tags: jsp, types, jstl, decimalformat

I have an input field like this:

```
<input type="number" name="myValue" id="myValue" required
    value="${not empty myValue ? myValue : 1.0}" />
```

It should be 1.0 until set otherwise.

This works fine in Chrome, but when I use Internet Explorer, it says something like

> This is not a valid date, please change.

I guess there's something wrong with `1.0` because Chrome automatically changes it to `1,0` (my local format for decimal places). When I try to set `1,0` manually in IE I get an exception, as my servlet can't convert it to `double`.

What can I do to set it format independent?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use step="any" and it seems to work.